# Qual é a tradução de "statement" dentro do âmbito da programação?

Tags: tradução, palavra-para-ideia

Estou montando um documento em português e preciso inserir um diagrama genérico, similar à imagem abaixo:

> [image]

Entretanto eu não sei como eu poderia traduzir a palavra "statement".

Os tradutores online me sugeriram "afirmação", dentre várias outras palavras que algo me diz que no contexto atual não representam bem a minha intenção.

Teria alguma palavra mais adequada para o cenário em questão?

Comment: O statement é um output para o utilizador ver?

Comment: Não necessariamente, pode ser uma linha contendo cálculo, chamada de função, declaração, inicialização de variáveis, outputs..

Comment: Cruzes credo, precisas de uma palavra que possa significar qualquer uma dessas coisas! De facto, _afirmação_ não me parece grande coisa, e _declaraçâo_ é só _uma_ das coisas que o statement pode ser.

Comment: Que tal *statement*? ;)

Comment: http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/ingles-portugues/statement

Comment: @JorgeB. que tal _estatamento_? :P

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Em ciência da computação temos os termos em inglês *statement*, *instruction*, *command*, *directive* e *declaration* com significados diferentes. Nenhum deles tem o significado da palavra *affirmation* da língua inglesa. Todos estes termos podem ser traduzidos assim:

- *affirmation* → **afirmação**
- *command* → **comando**
- *declaration* → **declaração**
- *directive* → **diretiva**
- *instruction* → **instrução**
- *statement* → ???

Aí chegamos no problema: Não há tradução direta para o termo *statement* no português! A tradução mais aproximada leva ao termo ***afirmação***, mas este em português é inadequado na ciência da computação, uma vez que tem o mesmo significado de *affirmation* em inglês, que é um termo inadequado ao contexto no qual é empregado.

Em geral, a tradução mais conveniente na minha experiência é como ***instrução***, uma vez que em linguagens de programação imperativas, todos os *statements* são *instructions* e quase sempre em que o termo *statement* é utilizado, o objetivo é referir-se a uma *instruction* (inclusive no fluxograma demonstrado na pergunta). Nos casos onde o *statement* corresponde a um **comando**, **diretiva** ou **declaração**, tal termo seria utilizado.

Nos casos aonde há ambiguidade ou generalização, de forma que *statement* não pode ser traduzido como ***instrução*** e nem se refere claramente a algum dos demais termos, convém então deixá-lo em inglês como *statement*.

O termo ***afirmação*** não é correto porque uma afirmação consiste apenas de atestar a veracidade de um fato, o que não corresponde ao propósito usado em uma linguagem de programação imperativa, que é o de especificar que uma determinada ação deve ser efetuada.

Comment: Como um programador, eu penso em  *statement* como uma instrucção de como fazer alguma coisa. Um exemplo seria `var foo = 55;`. O `var` é um `statement`. O `var` não faz nada por si só. Portanto, instrucção é mesmo o termo correcto.

Answer (score 11):

Eu pessoalmente uso "comando", cujo equivalente em inglês, "command", também pode ser usado nesse contexto. A [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) parece concordar com esse uso (procure pela palavra "comando" nesse artigo). Uma outra possibilidade seria "instrução", mas ela possui a desvantagem de poder ser confundida com instruções de programas de linguagem de máquina, que são menos expressivas.

Comment: Um comando é muito parecido a um  `statement`, mas, usando Javascript como exemplo, para `var foo = 'teste';` é incorrecto dizer que `var` é um comando. `var` não executa nada. Apenas diz que a variável pertence a um determinado bloco. Retirando o `var` continua a declarar a variável ou atribuí um novo valor a uma variável existente. O `var` não faz nada, apenas instrui em como proceder.

Comment: O manual da linguagem Lua 5.2 traduz [_statement_](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.3) por ["comando"](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/pt/manual.html#3.3), como você.

Answer (score 10):

## *Statement* → *Instrução*

Na tradução portuguesa de *Programming Perl*, o que eu tinha escrito originalmente com a palavra *Statements* em inglês tornou-se *Instruções* em português:

> ### Instruções  e declarações
>
> Um programa Perl consiste em uma sequencia de declarações e instruções. [...]
>
> #### Instruções simples
>
> Uma instrução simples é uma expressão avaliada por seus efeitos colaterais. Cada instrução simples precisa terminar com um ponto-e-vírgula, a menos que seja a instrução final em um bloco. [...]
>
> #### Instruções compostas
>
> Uma sequencia de instruções de um escopo é chamada de *bloco*.

— *Programação Perl, Terceira edição*, por Wall, [Christiansen](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/38/tchrist) e Orwant; O’Reilly and Associates; tradutor Daniel Vieira, Rio de Janeiro 2001.

Answer (score 9):

No seu comentário você disse que cada *statement* "pode ser uma linha contendo cálculo, chamada de função, declaração, inicialização de variáveis, outputs". No âmbito de programação isso é uma instrução. Pode não ser a tradução mais literal, mas é um termo bastante utilizado e facilmente reconhecido pelos programadores.

E mais: não que o Google Tradutor seja uma fonte 100% confiável, mas vale observar que ele traduz "statement" como "declaração", mas traduz "SQL statement" como "instrução SQL".

Comment: que tal mandamento? :)

Answer (score 7):

Note: I'm replying in English cause I'm Spanish and I am able to understand the question and comments but cannot write in Portuguese (sorry!).

I would probably use something more generic, such as *ação* (’action’).

I'm not 100% sure that *ação* would match exactly what you're looking for but it would sound OK for me in Spanish and would agree that *afirmação, declaração* or *instrução* are more restrictive and would probably not work (same in Spanish!).

Hope this helps.

Comment: An action would be to move a file, delete a record in a database or actually doing something. For example, `return foo;` is a statement. It doesn't do any actually thing. It hands over the value. `var`, for example, doesn't do anything besides identifying that the variable is created locally instead of globally (Javascript) or instead of specifying it's type (C#).

Answer (score 4):

Sorry I'm Spanish and I can only reply in English.

In Spanish, *statement* in this context is translated as ***sentencia*** (***sentença*** in Portguese). The OP's picture looks like a basic flow chart example, and Spanish literature always translates it as ***sentencia*** or ***bloque de sentencias***.

Edit: Please, also note that even in Spanish ***sentencia*** holds quite the same meaning as ***frase***; ***sentencia*** holds several meanings, and within this context it is more like an *instruction* or *command*. Also in this context, ***sentencia*** means ***statement***, not ***sentence***. In Spanish computer science literature, *statement* is never translated as ***frase***. Sorry not to help properly, just learning Português.

[Sentença (pt)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/senten%C3%A7a)
[Sentença (br)](http://www.dicio.com.br/sentenca/)
[Sentencia (es)](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=qhWyPcZyMDXX22Pl7uLX)

Comment: I messed up the previous comment completely. Then you would recommend the Portuguese word "frase". That's the closest to the spanish word "sentencia" in the sense of "oración gramatical." "Sentença" is used basically only for a sentece expressing a strong opinion, or a judge's final decision in a court of law.

Comment: @Jacinto I have only ever seen English *sentence* (in the sense of an independent clause with its own tensed verb and subject) translated as *frase*, be it in Spanish or Portuguese.

Comment: @tchrist I had no idea of the spanish word "sentencia". But I checked the reference in the answer, and the last meaning is Ling. Oración gramatical. So, I've just learned it.

Answer (score 3):

Para o caso de ajudar, aqui fica: na linguagem corrente o equivalente português mais próximo de *statement* é *declaração*.

[*Afirmação* (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/afirma%C3%A7%C3%A3o) tem mais a ver com defender a verdade de alguma coisa. É o ato de afirmar, que por sua vez significa: "dar por certo; corroborar; tornar firme; sustentar."

[*Declaração* (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o) é mais neutro. É o ato de declarar, que por sua vez tem como significado primário: "manifestar de modo claro e terminante; patentear, tornar conhecido dar a saber."

Comment: Bem lembrado. É importante mencionar, por outro lado, que "declaração" não é muito adequada no contexto dessa pergunta, pois tem um sentido técnico diferente.

Comment: @Arthur Pois, eu lembro-me dos meus tempos de programação, que as declarações consistiam precisamente em dar a conhecer no início de cada rotina as variáveis e coisas assim. Mas num esquema daqueles, em que ainda não se está a escrever código, talvez não houvesse perigo de confusão.

Comment: Como apontou o @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim, `declaração` não funciona bem porque no contexto de programação, um statement pode ser *muitas* coisas (por exemplo, [em C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173143.aspx)) incluindo declarações: uma declaração, uma atribuição, um "bloco" (de statements), uma invocação, uma expressão... talvez `comando` ou `frase` funcionem melhor.

Comment: O dicionário da porto editora confima: http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/ingles-portugues/statement

Answer (score 0):

Nos livros brasileiros programação os termos:

1. Declaração
2. Instrução
3. Comando

são utilizados intercambiavelmente para o termo *statement*.

Comment: Tua resposta está bem parecida com as demais já existentes. Sugiro adicionar mais informações ou referências para enriquecer tua resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Como dito anteriormente *declaração* e *instrução* funcionam. *Asserção* é uma tradução possível em alguns contextos, mas *declaração* é o usado na literatura disponível.